# Error installing nokogumbo gem with specific version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, sanitize, nokogumbo

I am trying to do bundle install on my project.
Ruby: 2.5.1
Rails: 5.0.7.2
Bundler: 1.17.3

But when doing the bundle install, it gives me this error with the nokogumbo gem and it doesn't install it, I'm using a mac.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZAl0.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's generally considered best practice to paste the error message into a code block instead of linking to an image. That way search engines can index the error message and others experiencing the same issue can find the answer as well.

Have you tried going through the suggestions here: https://github.com/Nuitka/Nuitka/issues/93

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
bundle config set force_ruby_platform true
bundle install
```

Otherwise, paste in your commands and the output so we can see a better view of what is going on.

Comment: above is my answer